# How do you make Korma output the SQL it would execute?

Tags: clojure, korma

I'm trying to get Korma to output the SQL it would execute so I can debug a problem I'm having, but the docs are very terse on how to use the as-sql function. Can anyone give me an example of how to make Korma output the SQL for an INSERT query?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

from: http://sqlkorma.com/api/0.3.0/korma.core.html

```
dry-run
(dry-run & body)
Wrap around a set of queries to print to the console all SQL that would 
be run and return dummy values instead of executing them.
```

Comment: Yep, that works with (insert ...) queries, so I'll accept it. I was trying to get (insert* ...) queries to do the same. But it's not strictly necessary since this works for (insert ...).

Answer (score 8):

If you want to get the SQL query as a string, there is also `sql-only`

```
(println     
    (sql-only
        (select users)))
```